# How to launch a method after a cell value has been edited in ag-grid?

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-ng2, ag-grid-angular

I have this simple column:
[image]

Here's its definition:

```
{
      headerName: "Activité",
      field: "activite",
      editable: true,
       , cellClass: "cell-wrap-text"
      }
```

Here's the method I want to launch every time the user enters a new input in that column.

```
  public UpdateActValue() {
      this.data.sendActToBia(this.params.data.activite);
      }
```

Here are my questions:
1/ Are there any ag-grid "native" way to launch a particular method after a cell value from a column has been edited?
2/ Should I simply define a custom cell renderer and do all the necessary work there?
Thank you!

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of the `cellValueChanged` event binding to detect changes in cell value.

On your component.html, you can simply bind the `onCellValueChanged()` method to the `cellValueChanged` event.

```
<ag-grid-angular 
.
.
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
(cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
>
```

And on your component.ts, you will define the `onCellValueChanged()` method, which will be fired every single time any cell value has changed.

```
onCellValueChanged(event) {
  // handle the rest here
}
```

You may read up more about grid cell editing and change detection over [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-editing/).

Comment: Thanks, I have just posted a complete answer. Just like yours but with a minor detail of detecting which column has been affected by the change. Thank you!

Comment: Btw, do you have any idea how I can detect in which the row the change happened? Just like I detected in which column?

Comment: @AhmedGhrib Yes, you can use `cellValueChanged` for that purpose too. On the very same method, you can detect the index of the changed row by doing `event.rowIndex`.

Comment: I have found a simple way: params.node.id with the same event listener. Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

I have just found a simple way to do this. I hope it helps.

> In grid.component.html:

Add this inside the grid definition:

```
  (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
```

> In the grid.component.ts:
>   Define the method:

```
onCellValueChanged(params) {
    const colId = params.column.getId();
    if (colId === "activite") {
      this.data.sendActToBia(params.data.activite);
}
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that there might be a case when onCellValueChanged is if you defined custom cell `valueSetter`, for example via gridOptions.

This is what was happening for my in Angular 6. Below if you uncomment valueSetter you will not get onCellValueChanged called.

```
private initGridOptions(mappingId: number) {
    this.gridOptions = {
        defaultColDef: {
            onCellValueChanged: (event) => {
                console.log("Fired for column");
                console.log(event);
            },

            // IF YOU UNCOMMENT Value Setter onCellValueChanged will not get fired
            // valueSetter: value => {
            //     return false;
            // },

        }
    };
}
```