# Update ag-grid cell values after bulk editing

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to update ag-grid, after cell values change in bulk instead of one value at a time. I know there's already a method  (cellvaluechanged) that gives you what value has been changed along with api and colDef. I also tried pasteEnd from ag-grid but this just works for paste, what if user just edits the cell value without copy pasting. What I am trying to do is have a method which will be called after a second or two, grabing all the values changed within ag-grid to avoid multiple rounds to backend. Possible Extension of this question: [How to launch a method after a cell value has been edited in ag-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56036593/how-to-launch-a-method-after-a-cell-value-has-been-edited-in-ag-grid)

Html

```
<ag-grid-angular [ngStyle]="{'height.px': innerHeight}" #agGridLevel class="ag-theme-balham"
                    [rowData]="rowData" [gridOptions]="gridOptions" [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef" [sideBar]="sideBar"
                    [columnDefs]="columnDefs" [excelStyles]="excelStyles" [rowSelection]="'multiple'"
                    (selectionChanged)="onSelectionChanged()" (rowClicked)="onRowClicked($event)"
                    [suppressCopyRowsToClipboard]="true"
                    [enableRangeSelection]="true"
                    (cellValueChanged)="onCellValueChanged($event)"
                    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
                    >
                </ag-grid-angular>
```

component.ts file

P.S. I know the method would still call backend multiple times even with timeout. This was just to show what I was trying to do.

```
onCellValueChanged(params) {
    console.log("Callback onCellValueChanged:", params);
    if (params.newValue) {
      this.changedValue.push({
        field: params.colDef.field,
        newValue: params.newValue.trim(),
        id: params.data.id
      });
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.updateCellValuesInDb(this.changedValue)
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
```

Would help a lot if someone knows how to bulk load the whole cell values changed after a second or two instead of sending every single value changed. Please advice.

Thank you

Comment: I had to deal with a similar situation but what helped for me was there was a button for the user to accept the bulk update so maybe you can compromise and create a button like so as well and once it clicks you can do `this.updateCellValuesInDb`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. The only reason I am reluctant to add a button is that it will take away the beauty of ag-grid excel like copy pasting. I was looking for more of a method/event that is provided out of the box from ag-grid.

Comment: Just use mostly your current method (collect changes in memory), but only allow `updateCellValuesInDb` to be called at most once every "second or two" with [`debounce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) or [`throttle`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use Interval based on comments. What happens is once the cell value changes, onCellValueChanged event is fired, from which I get changed value, Id of the row along with the actual field name. setTimeout() on the values changed just in case if there's 10-20 values pasted together to avoid back and forth backend calls.

Update CellValue then sets interval(500).

In the final step, **isCellValueUpdated** boolean declared as false in the component will handle the multiple calls to backend and bulk load will be done once per actual request for multiple records.

```
    onCellValueChanged(params) {
        console.log('Callback onCellValueChanged:', params);
        if (params.newValue) {
          this.changedValue.push({
            field: params.colDef.field,
            newValue: params.newValue.trim(),
            id: params.data.id
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.updateCellValues(this.changedValue);
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
      private updateCellValues(values: IGridChangedValues[]) {
        const changeBooleanAfterValuesChange = interval(500);
        this.updateDb({ values, changeBooleanAfterValuesChange });
      }


      private updateDb(
    { values, changeBooleanAfterValuesChange }:
      { values: IGridChangedValues[]; changeBooleanAfterValuesChange: Observable<number>; }) {
    if (!this.isCellValueUpdated) {
      this.isCellValueUpdated = true;
      this._studyLevelService.updateCellValuesInDb(values).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(
        (result: boolean) => {
          if (result) {
          } else {
            this._dialogs.alert(new AlertDialogOptions(
              'Error',
              'Error Updating values'));
          }
          changeBooleanAfterValuesChange.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(
            () => this.isCellValueUpdated = false
          )
        })
    }
  }
```

I was hoping there might be a better solution out there to avoid intervals and timeouts, but I think that's the best technique available for ag-grid right now